# Use parent outside of class php

Tags: php, inheritance

Given

```
abstract class A {
  public function __get($key) {
    ...
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function __get($key) {
    ...
  }
}

class C {
  public function test($bObject) {
    //Call the __get function of A on the object of B
  }
}
```

How would I call A::__get on an object of B from C::test? I've looked into using a callable on class A::__get and binding it to the object of class B, or using parent, but neither of those methods seem to help.

Comment: If you can you modify class `B`, add `public function __parentget($key) { parent::__get($key); }`. Then you can call `$bObject->__parentget($key);` from class `C`.

Comment: @kmoser: You should not introduce own methods with a name starting with two underscores `__...`  as they are reserved (by convention) to PHP internal stuff. Just noting, what you suggest is working well regardless of the name "issue". Consider to add an interface and make the class final anyway thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP one way you can do that is with reflection (*introspection* or also *meta-programming*), as by the class/object design, the encapsulation normally forbids it.

Given the following from the class definitions in question:

```php
$b = new B();
$b->test;
```

It works by obtaining the [closure of the parents method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getclosure.php) with the **B** object (e.g. the `$bObject` in your question or `$b` in the example here) and then calling it:

```php
(new ReflectionObject($b))
    ->getParentClass()
    ->getMethod('__get')
    ->getClosure($b)('test'); // or: ->invoke($b, 'test');
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/0tj26 and output for PHP 7.3.0 - 7.3.29, 7.4.0 - 7.4.21, 8.0.0 - 8.0.8:

```
string(8) "B::__get"
string(4) "test"
string(8) "A::__get"
string(4) "test"
```

Comment: Nice one, got same result with invoke

Comment: Yes, you had to pass the $b object there-in, too. With closure it is already bound, so you could pass it around, but technically it's the same.

Comment: I love when I find `Warning: This function is currently not documented; only its argument list is available. ` in php documentation. Thanks for your help! I would never have found this!

Comment: Actually I wondered about the warning as well. Because the docs page has more than just the parameters. I guess the warning might be a bit dated. I know about other docs pages where that kind of warning really fully applies. But still then, in PHP a small script is just around the corner. Learning by doing is best anyway, contributing to the PHP docs well possible, too!

Comment: @user3117152: Did the answer also clarify the part you had in your question that you already tried with closure and re-binding for you? I think it is not fully answered, or at least not totally clear to me: You wrote in the question that you created a callable from/for `A::__get` and I wonder a bit how that is possible. The binding $b to it you have not outlined (with code) but I assume it is with closure and that would have changed $this, but I'm kind of puzzled about the callable part and this could perhaps complete the answer.

Comment: @hakre Everything worked for how I needed it. I was using this with laravel for their __get when I had over-written it in a sub-model.

Comment: Ah, thanks for sharing the insight. IMHO there is no need to be shy about it, I think it would be great to make the use-case more prominent in the question already.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the ReflexionClass and the getParent method.

```
$objectB;
$key = 'key';

$reflectorB = new ReflectionObject($objectB);
$reflectorA = $reflectorB->getParentClass();
$method = $reflectorA->getMethod('__get');
return $method->invoke($objectB, $key);
```